# How to add price from ArrayList

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<ProductModel> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to multiply the meal price and meal qty of some items and make a grand total.

So, here is my code. Please help me out

```
double totalPrices = Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealprice()) + Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealqty());

            for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {

                    totalPrices += products.get(i);
            }

            tv_totalamount.setText("Total Amount to be Paid : " + totalPrices + "");
```

Comment: You said you need to mutiply then y use + operator, Instead add use * operator to sum of meals..  Change this `double totalPrices = Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealprice()) + Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealqty());` to `double totalPrices = Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealprice()) * Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealqty());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor cahnges can solve your problem.

```
double totalPrices = Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealprice()) + Double.parseDouble(productModel.getMealqty());

                for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {

                        totalPrices += products.get(i).getPrice();
                }

                tv_totalamount.setText("Total Amount to be Paid : " + totalPrices + "");
```